# KeyError: 'user' -- after part of file has already processed

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm trying to create a retweet/mention network from Twitter using Python, and I've been able to figure out a lot of it as I go.  Except, now that I've moved onto testing my code from a small sample to a larger sample, I've getting a strange KeyError that I don't understand.  I'm sure I'm probably missing something simple, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

The goal is read through the tweets and create a relationship between users if, first one user retweets another, then, if no retweet present, create a relationship between users in one mentions one another (including multiple mentions on new lines in a single tweet).  And If either a retweet or mention exist, print the tweet author only.

**The error I'm getting is below:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "...path/to/file.py", line 28, in <module>
        print tweet_time , "\t" , tweet['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , "TWEET"
KeyError: 'user'
```

**Code:**

```
import json
import time

data = []

for line in open('tweets.json'):
    try:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
    except:
        pass

tweet = data[0]

tweet_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))

for tweet in data:
    ## if the key 'retweeted_status' is in the dict, print 
    if tweet.has_key('retweeted_status'):
        print tweet_time , "\t" , tweet['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , tweet['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , "RETWEET"

    ## if there is a mention in the dict, print
    elif 'entities' in tweet and len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) > 0:
        for u2 in tweet['entities']['user_mentions']:
            print tweet_time , "\t" , tweet['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , u2['screen_name'] , "\t" , "MENTION"

    ## if there is no retweet and no mention, print
    else:
        print tweet_time , "\t" , tweet['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , "\t" , "TWEET"
```

Comment: One of your `tweet` objects has no `'user'` key. Just take that into account in your code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, you are right.  Apparently my data was rate limited, and there were lines that were just {"limit":{"track":30".  After removing those lines, it ran without error.